# Kubectl: Fail to get logs per label

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When I use the following command:

```
k logs <podname>-<podhash>
```

I get the pod log as expected.

But suppose I have multiple instances of this pod. For example:

```
k logs <podname>-<podhash1>
k logs <podname>-<podhash2>
k logs <podname>-<podhash3>
```

If I use

```
k logs -l app=podname
```

shouldn't I get an output of some aggregation of all these pods?

Because I'm not.

I guess I get only last 10 lines of one or all of the logs.

Comment: No, `kubectl logs` only gives output from a single container (not just a single pod but only one container in a multi-container pod).  Stack Overflow is about programming problems; you could write a program using a Kubernetes SDK that tried to read all of the logs in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

`k logs -l app=podname` will only print 10 logs.

The tail argument when using a selector will print logs of a pod to 10 lines length by default.

By executing the below command you will get the output logs to 100 lines:

```
kubectl logs --tail=100  <podname>
```

For logs from all containers in pods you need to give

```
kubectl logs <podname> --all-containers=true
```